# Reshaping numpy array of images results in extra dimension

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, scikit-learn

I have 440 images with the same size 924 x 640 and three channels. I load them via

```py
image_data = []
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(store, '*.jpg')):
    image_data.append(plt.imread(filename))
```

Then I make a numpy ndarray from this list:

```py
image_np_orig = np.array(image_data)
```

This array has a shape `(440,)` and it consists of elements with shape of `(924, 640, 3)`. I want to make some t-SNE transformations on this array of images, so I want to reshape the array to make it's shape look like `(440, 1)`:

```py
image_np = image_np_orig.reshape(image_np_orig.shape[0], -1)
```

### Expectation / Reality

I expect to see an array `image_np` of shape `(440, 1)` where each element of the first dimension (`axis=0`) is an array of shape `(924, 640, 3)`. However I get an array `image_np` of shape `(440, 1)`, where each element of the first dimension is an array of shape `(1,)` and in *these* arrays each element of their respective first dimensions is of shape `(924, 640, 3)`.

### What I've tried

I've tried

```py
image_np = image_np_orig[:, np.newaxis]
```

with the same results.

I`ve also tried

```py
image_np = np.stack(image_np_orig)
```

which lead to `image_np` with the shape of `(440, 924, 640, 3)` and then I got the mistake during the t-SNE transform:

```py
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, init='pca')
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(image_np)
```

returns `ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <=2.`

### Probably relevant

It may be relevant that `image_np_orig` has dtype `object` and `image_np_orig[0]` has dtype `uint8`. If this is relevant then how can I reshape arrays of different types?

Comment: If you start with a (400,) object dtype array, and reshape it to (400,1), then the shape will be that.  Indexing on the first dimension then gives a (1,) object dtype array.  What's puzzling about that?  `stack` is creating a 4d array.  I think you need a clearer idea of what the the `fit` code really requires.

Comment: If `arr` has shape (3,4), then `arr[0]` has shape (4,).  `arr(0,0)` is element, whose identity depends on the `dtype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an array of shape `(440, 1, 924, 640, 3)`, but you actually need `(440, 924, 640, 3)`

Try:

```
image_np = image_np_orig.squeeze()
```

This will squeeze out the unnwanted dimension.

Comment: This line of code produces `image_np` of shape `(440,)` and I need a shape of `(440, 1)` to feed to `TSNE`. Edited my initial question to clear this detail and also the shape of `image_np_orig`

Comment: Under "Expectation / Reality", you have used the phrase "first dimension". By that, do you mean the left-most dimension (axis 0) or the one after that (axis 1) ? I guess that is what is confusing me.

Comment: "First dimension" means axis 0, there is only one element along the next axis. Edited my initial post.

Comment: @BorisKalinin, Seen your edit of "Expectation / Reality", and I have this question about your expectation. You say you expect `image_np` to have a shape of `(440, 1)`, and each element of axis0 must have a shape `(924,640,3)`. But if `image_np` gets a shape of `(440,1)`, it implies that each element of axis0 of `image_np` is a 1-D array of length 1 (a 1-D array having a single element). Each element of axis0 couldn't be an array/object of shape `(924,640,3)` in such a case.

Comment: I would definitely agree if I haven't seen with my own eyes: `image_np.shape` -> `(440,1)`; `image_np[0].shape` -> `(1,)`; `image_np[0][0].shape` -> `(924, 640, 3)`. And I just want `image_np.shape` -> `(440, 1)`; `image_np[0].shape` -> `(924, 640, 3)`

Comment: I suppose these 3 shapes that you just mentioned in the recent comment, they are the "Reality" shapes and not the "Expectation" shapes. My last comment was entirely about your Expectation shapes. I was try to say that either your Expectation is not properly expressed, or it's self-contradicting and hence cannot be met. With this clarification, could you pls re-read my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the first approach doesn't work for you. But since `image_np = np.stack(image_np_orig)` returns the `4D` data, you can go from there:

```
image_np = np.stack(image_np_orig).reshape(len(image_np_orig), -1)
```

Comment: This gave me an `image_np` of shape `(440, 1774080)` and each element of the first dimension has a shape of `(1774080,)`. And when I fed this array to `TSNE` my computer froze. Seems like something with the memory and I'm pretty sure it does not have to be like that, as I'm doing a training exercise.

Comment: This gives you the expected dimension. I would expect that t-SNE freezes on that many dimensions as well.